# Interface both up and down?

Tags: iproute

```
$ ip link | grep vboxnet
10: vboxnet0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
```

In the angle brackets, it says `UP`. What do the angle brackets indicate?

Further in the line, it claims `state DOWN`. This seems to conflict with the earlier information. Is the interface up or down?

In the manual pages, `ip-link`, `ip`, and `ip-address`, I cannot find what the angle brackets mean.

Comment: Related (about flags in angle brackets): https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/335077/315749

Comment: Similar:  [How does iproute2’s `ip link show` determine link state?](https://superuser.com/q/1365825/354511)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Within the angle brackets there is a list of *flags* (= on/off type properties) of the interface. After the flags,
non-binary properties (also known as attributes) are listed.

There are two concepts you should be aware of:

- *administrative state*: the state you've commanded the network interface to be (i.e., active or not)
- *operational state*: the state the network interface is actually in

If you configure the network interface, its administrative state will be set to `UP` immediately, but the operational state will change only after the physical interface is successfully powered up, the link pulse from the other end has been detected, autonegotiation has been completed (if applicable) and the interface and the driver are fully ready to pass traffic.

In the `ip link` output, the `UP` flag describes the interface's administrative state. There are two related flags: `LOWER_UP` that gets added when the card is physically ready for traffic, and `NO-CARRIER` if there is no signal from the other end. These two flags would be considered parts of the operational state.

So, your `vboxnet0` interface has been commanded to be up (= active), but currently there are no virtual machines connected to this virtual interface, so the interface is flagged `NO-CARRIER` and is therefore operationally down, at least until some virtual machine starts using it.

The actual kernel-level flags are called `IFF_UP` for "interface administratively enabled" and `IFF_RUNNING` for "interface operationally ready". The old `ifconfig` command used to just show them directly (without the `IFF_` prefix), but the absence of `RUNNING` was not easy to notice, so `ip link` command now has this logic:

```
 IF (IFF_UP is set) AND (IFF_RUNNING is not set)
 THEN display an extra flag "NO-CARRIER" in the flags field
```

The kernel-level flags are described in the [`netdevice(7)` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netdevice.7.html),
under ["DESCRIPTION"](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netdevice.7.html#DESCRIPTION) → "Ioctls".

Comment: The question has been posted countless time; your answer is the only exhaustive answer I found. In particular, the `ip link` command logic fully clarified the meaning of `IFF_RUNNING`. (On the contrary, the man page _did not_.)

Comment: [This (“operstates”) document at kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/operstates.txt) looks like a good reference.